# Bitmap not appearing in ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

While trying to display a JPG from a URL I'm having an issue getting the image to appear in my ImageView. I'm able to open a URLConnection, pull the image down in an InputStream, decode that stream into Bitmap. I can even get values for the height and width of the bitmap. I set the bitmap to the ImageView and can still get a height for the Drawable. However, the image still does not appear in my application. Any ideas of what I could be missing? Thanks for any help.

```
try{
    URL imgURL = new URL(imgLocation);
    URLConnection conn = imgURL.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 25);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

    if(bm != null){
        System.err.println("Image Height: " + bm.getHeight());
        System.err.println("Image Width: " + bm.getWidth());
    } else {
        System.err.println("bm is null!!!");
    }

    img.setImageBitmap(bm);
    System.err.println("Drawable Height: " + img.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Print out the exception that occurred
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answer directly to your question, but I can suggest alternative solution for this need.

Using ImageView will cause you lots of issues, for usability.
You need to avoid screen locking, and re-dowloading image is bad from optimization perspective.

I would suggest much simpler & efficient solution; you can use WebImageView from Droid-Fu.
it works like a charm. you just pass the url of the image, and you let WebImageView handle downloading, showing progress and even caching.

here is Droid-Fu's playgorund on GitHub (search for 'droid-fu')

p.s. I also did some extensions to this caching mechanism, already released in my github playground (search for 'wareninja')